# Reported error after booting

Tags: boot, lubuntu, xorg, crash

I've been using Lubuntu for 5 years or more without any problems so far. Just purchased a brand new Dell XPS 13-9350 with 256 GB SSD and I freshly installed Lubuntu 16.04 64 bit edition.

This ultrabook has a very high screen resolution (3200 x 1800 px) which I had to downgrade to 1366 x 768 px, otherwise most programs had virtually unreadable text of very, very small size.

Unfortunately, I frequently get an error issue upon booting the system which also suggests reporting so that it could be eventually fixed.

The error has the following Title: Xorg crashed with SIGABRT in pixman_region_selfcheck().

I would attach a image but have not found how to do that.

Two of the many additional programs I installed are LibreOffice 5.2.1.2 and BricsCAD V16.2.14 (x64) Rev.44207.

The first one will sometimes blank the screen and reboot the O/S. A request for help from LO suggested the installation of soffice-common. This somewhat reduced the problem to more occasional crashes but failed to completely solve it.

A Support Request was also filed with Bricsys and they also suggested several solutions. None have worked until now. In this case opening a drawing presents an initial blurred image. This is easily corrected with a redraw or a regen command. However, during work sessions, some operations cause unrequested zooming into other parts of the drawing. This is normally corrected with the scroll wheel of the mouse, which returns the view to a point very near the previous one. This is quite annoying and makes working properly very difficult.

I've mentioned this two issues as both seem to be related to a possible display driver problem. BTW I downloaded and installed the latest release of the Intel driver. This did not change things at all.

Will appreciate any comments or guidance you can supply on the matter.

Thank you.

Comment: Does the error occur during BOOTING, or after LOGGING IN? Does the error occur if you set your screen resolution back to 3200 x 1800 px? Cheers, Al

Comment: Sorry for the mistype. The error occurs after loggin in. Apparently the error does not occur if I go back to 3200 x 1800 px, but then ALL programs tried occupy 1/4 of the screen size and I need a magnifier to read the text or see the icons.

Comment: OK, we're making progress. Check your **Startup Applications** for items that start when logging in, that might have any relations to Libreoffice and BricsCAD? Disable them. Change the display back to 1366 x 768 px. Then log out, then log back in and see if the error goes away. Cheers, Al

Comment: I changed screen resolution back to 1366 x 768 but it really did not change the behaviour at all. The autostart applications I have do not seem to be related to either LibreOffice or Bricscad. I have a couple of screen captures with the list of them but I don't know how to attach these to the message.

Comment: Just to confirm, you don't see the error at 3200x1800, but you do see the error at 1366x768, yes? If you set it to 3200x1800, and then go to `System Settings/Universal Access/Seeing/Large Text` = ON, does that make it bearable? Cheers, Al

Comment: I want to update my initial request in the following terms:

Comment: Sorry, just added my comment while still unfinished. The reported issue is still occurring (even more frequently) after logging in. in the meantime, several updates of Lubuntu were installed but no change occurred. However, the problem with BricsCAD was solved with the help of their team. Setting a system variable to 0 did the trick and the program now works properly.

Comment: Following the above.  This does not happen with Libre Office. If invoked from the Menu it will invariably blank the screen and reboot. If an existing file is opened all goes well. Setting screen resolution to 3200x1800 will display program windows in the upper left quarter of the screen, scaled down to unusable proportion.

Comment: Update: The problem with LibreOffice was solved after upgrading to version 5.2.3.3. The problem with "Xorg crashed with SIGABRT in pixman_region_selfcheck()" still occurs immediately after loggin in every time.

Comment: Does the problem occur if you log into the root or guest accounts? Does the problem occur if you disable ALL of the items in Startup Applications?

Comment: I only have a single account. No guest account at all. I disabled all items in Startup Applications and apparently the problem went away. I then reenabled the same applications one by one. Upon reaching Update Notifier the same error message reapeared. The remaining applications did not cause any problems. However, in the end, I left Update Notifier on and got no error for a few days. I has now reappeared with even more frequency, always after logging in an now at any time during a session. I cannot find a pattern. I will now disable the Update Notifier and keep on testing.

Comment: This is to inform you that disabling Update Notifier from the Startup Applications list has solved the problem. However, this still implies that such behaviour should not happen and must be attended to. For the time being I resort to Software Updater from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Starting on October 7, and after extended testing via the comments, it was determined that there was an application in the `Startup Applications` that was causing the problem immediately after logging into the system.

The `BricsCAD` and `LibreOffice` application problems were solved with support team help, and with updating the software.

`Software Updater` does not have to be done manually. If you open `Software & Updates`, and go to the `Updates` tab, you can set your software update frequency to your desire.